# Vite multiple entry points without [folder]/index.html pattern

Tags: html, vite

I'm new to vite and trying to migrate from a gulp workflow to vite. I want to output multiple html files in this format: (Not like dist/about/index.html)

```
...
src
|_index.html
|_about.html
|_contact.html
|_assets

dist
|_index.html
|_about.html
|_contact.html
|_assets
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these files are static and should be just copied use the `public` folder:

https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory

But if these files contains JS that should be bundled that you have a multiple entry points setup. Multiple entry points are set with the `input` rollup option. The output files could be mapped with the `output.entryFileNames`. All file names could be globbed with `fast-glob` for example.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig(() => {
    return {
        build: {
            rollupOptions: {
                input: ['index.html', 'about.html'],
                output: {
                    entryFileNames: ['index.html', 'about.html']
                }
            },
        },
    };
});
```

You can read the following related Vite/Rollup questions with my answers:

[How do I completely disable chunking in Vite and Rollup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76517758/how-do-i-completely-disable-chunking-in-vite-and-rollup/76517896#76517896)

[How can I customize the output filename when multiple inputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76461277/how-can-i-customize-the-output-filename-when-multiple-inputs/76462165#76462165)

And all my Vite/Rollup answers for reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A14098260+Vite