# Add another hash file to build/static, can I build multiple entryFileNames from rollup? vite-build

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, rollup, rollupjs

I'm trying to place a blank `element[hash].js` file inside my `build/static/js` directory after doing vite-build. The `main[hash].js` was working fine because entryFileNames requires a string, yet I've seen entryFileNames as a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76461277/how-can-i-customize-the-output-filename-when-multiple-inputs) returning an array, I'm using typescript.

Before was working:

```
rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        name: 'app',
        entryFileNames: 'static/js/main.[hash].js',
        dir: './build',
```

My failing attempt:

```
  rollupOptions: {
      input: ['./src/main.tsx', './public/static/js/element.js'],
      output: {
        name: 'app',
        entryFileNames: ['static/js/main.[hash].js', 'static/js/element.[hash].js'],
        dir: './build',
```

Typescript error:

```
Types of property 'entryFileNames' are incompatible.
    Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string | ((chunkInfo: PreRenderedChunk) => string) | undefined'.ts(2322)
```

Any ideas?