# What is the purpose of `entryNames` on Rollup and how I can programatically use it?

Tags: rollup, rollupjs

I am read the [Rollup Configuration documentation](https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/) and found out there is this `entryNames` for `input`.

```
type InputOptions = string | string[] | { [entryName: string]: string }
```

What is the purpose of this `entryName`?

What I already understand of `entryName` is used to set `[name]` at output. I try it and yeah, it works as expected. But is it just it? Is there any purpose of this `entryName`? Maybe such as I can get what are current entry is in transform via Hooks or Transform function?

In summarize, What is the purpose of this `entryName`? How could I take advantage and utilised it fully? (beside only changing the `options.entryFileNames`)

---

Someone mention this question duplicated and I found this question is answer me up:

- [How can I customize the output filename when multiple inputs in rollup.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76462165/5832341)

I can get the `entryName` by using `chunk.name`. But there is something I cannot figure out, how to get the same `chunk.name` or getting this chunk info at before or during transformation? Before or during `plugins[].transform` hook called.