# Vite and Rollup output structure

Tags: hash, build, frontend, vite, rollup

I have an app on create-react-app that builds with its structure like in a screen [webpack-build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tcpl.png). How can I manage the same structure in Vite? I got only the 'build' output folder, but cannot manage the inner structure in there.

Here is my Vite-Rollup output config:

```
build: {
    emptyOutDir: true,
        rollupOptions: {
        output: {
            dir: 'build',
        },
    },
},
```

And here is what I've got on build success:
[Vite-build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEP1A.png)

I already tried playing with the `output.entryFileNames` function, didn't help. Here is what I've got

```
entryFileNames: (chunk) => {
    const extension = chunk.facadeModuleId.slice(
        chunk.facadeModuleId.indexOf('.') + 1,
    )

    return `${extension}/[hash].${extension}`
},
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I customize the output filename when multiple inputs in rollup.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76461277/how-can-i-customize-the-output-filename-when-multiple-inputs-in-rollup-js)