# How to configure vite to generate such a directory structure?

Tags: vite

I created a new vanilla app with pnpm create vite. I have the following directory structure，
我有一下目录结构：

```
├──── src
│      └──A
│         └──images
│              └──a.jpg
│         └──main.js
│      └──B
│         └──images
│              └──b.jpg
│         └──main.js
│      └──C
│         └──images
│              └──c.jpg
│         └──main.js
└────index.html
```

index.html：

```
<body>
  <script type="module" src="src/A/main.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="src/B/main.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="src/C/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

How to package it into the following structure in vite？
如何在vite中打包成一下结构：

```
│──A
│  └──a.jpg
│  └──main.js
│──B
│  └──b.jpg
│  └──main.js
│──C
│  └──c.jpg
│  └──main.js
└──index.html
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I customize the output filename when multiple inputs in rollup.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76461277/how-can-i-customize-the-output-filename-when-multiple-inputs-in-rollup-js)

Comment: How to get the path in assetFileNames?如何在assetFileNames获取路径？

Comment: you store it in a variable and use it in `assetFileNames` and other places you like